# Reading a cookie on socket.io

Tags: node.js, cookies, redis, socket.io

I am stuck scratching my head dealing with cookies. I understand how to read cookies from within the "auth" function below, as I can read my cookie named "identity". The problem I face is that I cannot access that same cookie from within any of the **io.sockets.on()** function. This cookie holds an OpenID value, representing the user.

```
io.configure(function () {
  function auth (data, fn) {
    var cookies = parse_cookies(data.headers.cookie);
    console.log('IDENTITY: ' + cookies.identity);

        client.hget('user:'+cookies.identity, 'verified', function (err , reply) {
            fn(null, reply == 1);    
        });
  };
  io.set('authorization', auth);
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    client.get('user:'+**COOKIE HERE**+':name', function (err , reply) {
        socket.emit('example', reply); 
      });
});
```

Comment: i'm not 100% sure on this but socket.handshake.headers should contain the cookies